# Global variable created in index.php is not accessible in channel entries

Tags: global-variables, expressionengine

I am working on a multi-langual site with Expression Engine.
For multiple languages I use this guide here : http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine/

where I create a global variable on index.php

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['language'] = "de";
```

Now I can use the `{language}` in templates which is great. Now I also want to use Global Variables from with the Channel Entries, for this purpose I used this plugin : http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code , now with the help of this plugin I can use all other global variables I create in backend in the channel entries, but when I use the `{language}` it doesn't work because I didn't create it in backend, and it gets printed as "{language}"

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: Try a standard global variable like {site_url} - does that parse when used in a text field? My guess is it's not achievable as globals and conditionals are parsed later than the processing of the allow-ee-code add-on...?

Comment: @PeterLewis yes, {site_url} is accessable, even the global variables that are created using the backend are accessible. but not the ones that I create in index.php for language.

Comment: Do other global_vars that you create in index.php work?

Comment: @AllInOne no they don't because they will only work in the template file. when I use using the ee tags.

Comment: Have you tried creating entries for these global variables that you are setting in index.php in the exp_global_variables table? You could still set them in index.php but as long as the names match.